# Manifold over a Finite Field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I'm trying to either associate a manifold with a finite field, or, ideally find a way of considering finite fields as manifolds, in a non-trivial manner.

I hope to be able to use this to extend topological methods to finite projective planes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What topology ?

Comment: As a point set, it is at least a subset of its affine line, that is, the spectrum of the polynomial ring in one variable, which resembles a manifold at least insofar as that it is a regular scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Probably what you're looking for is the étale cohomology (and other étale versions of classical topological material) of the projective spaces over finite fields, which can be regarded as schemes.  Schemes can be regarded as a natural (though quite vast) generalization of complex projective manifolds.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the [spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring) of the finite field you are considering. It is an affine scheme whose underlying topological space is a singleton, but which is carrying information through its sheave of rings of functions.